# grunt uglify usermin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, cdn, grunt-usemin

i am new to grunt ,i was watching this video..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIbfDxF69c8

original html(app/index.html)

```
<!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

minified html(build/index.html)

```
<script src="scripts/libmin.js"></script>
```

i need

```
<script src="http://www.cdn.cdn/cdnfoler/libmin.js"></script>
```

my grunt code:

```
  grunt.registerTask('bobthebuilder',[
  'copy:task0',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concat',
  'cssmin',
  'uglify',
  'usemin'
  ]);
```

How can i replace the minified code folder to cdn url.
as i am plamning to upload this minified code to cdn.

Comment: Where does `<script src="scripts/libmin.js"></script>` sit in you index.html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a function out of the box, but maybe should be a good idea to integrate cdnify grunt task to your workflow to do that

Take a look:  https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify

you can make something like

```
dist: {
    html: ['<%=dist %>/*.html']
  }
```